# Func.apply does not work on a prototype method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to call a prototype method via func.apply and it loses context. So i cannot use "this.

For instance,

```
function Apple (type) {
this.type = type;
this.color = "red";}


Apple.prototype.getInfo = function() {
return this.color + ' ' + this.type + ' apple';};
```

If later on i will call the getInfo prototype function with func.apply(this, args) i am not able to get this.color or this.type.They are undefined.

While if i call it the usual way it runs smoothly.

```
Apple a = new Apple(1);
a.getInfo();
```

Comment: `var a = new Apple(1);` typo?

Comment: And you're sure that `this` is a reference to your function instance at the point of calling apply? If you're calling it outside the function then I doubt it. Try `.apply(a, ..)` instead if your example is anything to go by

Comment: Please share a working snippet demonstrating your issue.

Comment: Please post the relevant part of the code where you are using the `apply` that does not work!

Comment: I worked it out. I needed to pass the object itself instead of this. So i won;t lose context.